# Error when trying to write, save or read files in deployed flask app on vercel

Tags: python, html, flask

Basically I'm, trying to select an image from my local PC and load and display it onto the WebSite by selecting the image at first, and then saving it into a folder in the working directory called uploads.

Anytime I deploy the app and run the function it returns `"Internal Server Error 500"` in a new page. And, anytime I take off the `"file.save"`, it runs without any issues.

Also face the same, error when I try reading or writing a text file using `"with open"`. Could it be that flask is not allowed to load images locally?...or is there a problem with my code?

Everything works fine when I run it locally but after deployment I encounter these issues.

Here's my code:

```py
path = os.getcwd()
upload_folder = os.path.join(path, 'static', 'uploads') app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = upload_folder

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_image(): 
    file = request.files['file']
    if file:
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
return render_template('index.html', filename=filename)
```